# Calculate polygon intersection area with GPC or Clipper

Tags: c++, geometry, polygons, boost-geometry

I have a 2D particle system, where the particles are represented as ellipses. I need to calculate ellipse - ellipse overlap areas, but this is a hard analytical problem [Ellipse-Ellipse Overlap](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3787). I now represent my ellipses as 20-gons, so that they are "polygonized" and I am using `Boost.Geometry` to make the necessary calculations.

However, very often, I get an exception from `Boost.Geometry` : `boost.geometry overlay invalid input exception`. I searched and found that this is a known bug of `boost.Geometry` and there is no fix as of version 1.53. Even the documentation on upcoming v1.54 does not say anything about fixing this problem.

I have stumbled upon [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) and [GPC - General Polygon Clipper Library](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/alan/software/). They seem to do what I want, but they only output boolean results. Does anyone know if there is a way to output the area of the calculated intersections with these libraries? I guess that since the intersection is stored in memory as some kind of polygon, I could use triangulation or some other method to calculate the area.
Any pointers would be really appreciated!

The `Boost overlay` exception is consistent in MSVC 2010 and 2012 under Win7 x64, MinGW and Qt 4.8.1 under Linux Mint 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're wrong about Clipper and GPC "*they only output boolean results*". Both libraries calculate intersection polygon - for example, look at the code snippet with picture on Clipper page.

Comment: Actually, you were partly correct. In the code snippet, you can see in the end that for the `Clipper` `c` object Angus uses this: `c.Execute(ctIntersection, solution, pftNonZero, pftNonZero);`, which is a Boolean expression. But in his benchmark, he is calculating areas and I found a way to modify his code to my needs. I will mark your answer as the correct one, as it got me thinking and set me on the right track! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you submit a ticket into the Boost ticket system? Including a sample of a geometry pair giving invalid input exceptions? The error can have several causes, either it is indeed invalid, or it is a bug in the library. Some of these issues are fixed per 1.54.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will submit a ticket. It is very good to hear that this may be fixed in 1.54!

Answer (score 0):

In Angus' benchmark of Clipper with the other libraries, he has a method for polygon Area calculation. I used that and modified his ellipse method. The result is the following:

```
void Ellipse2Poly(double theta, double A1, double B1, double H1, double K1, Poly& p)
{ 
    const double pi = 3.1415926535898, tolerance = 0.125;
    const int n = 30;
    double step = pi/(double)n;
    double a = A1; // Long semi-axis length
    double b = B1; // short semi-axis length
    double xc = H1; // current X position
    double yc = K1; // current Y position
    double sintheta = sin(theta);
    double costheta = cos(theta);
    double t = 0;
    p.resize(2*n+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2*n+1; i++)
    {
        p[i].x = xc + a*cos(t)*costheta - b*sin(t)*sintheta;
        p[i].y = yc + a*cos(t)*sintheta + b*sin(t)*costheta;
        t += step;
    }
}
```

And the area calculation is:

```
double OverlapArea(Poly poly1, Poly poly2)
{
    Poly clip;
    Polys polys_poly1, polys_poly2, polys_clip;
    polys_poly1.resize(1);
    polys_poly2.resize(1);
    polys_clip.resize(1);
    polys_poly1[0] = poly1;
    polys_poly2[0] = poly2;
    polys_clip[0] = clip;
    Polygons clipper_polys_poly1, clipper_polys_poly2, clipper_polys_clip;
    LoadClipper(clipper_polys_poly1,polys_poly1);
    LoadClipper(clipper_polys_poly2,polys_poly2);
    ClipType op = ctIntersection;
    Clipper cp;
    cp.AddPolygons(clipper_polys_poly1,ptSubject);
    cp.AddPolygons(clipper_polys_poly2,ptClip);
    cp.Execute(op,clipper_polys_clip,pftEvenOdd,pftEvenOdd);
    if(clipper_polys_clip.size() != 0)
    {
        UnloadClipper(polys_clip,clipper_polys_clip);
        return Area(polys_clip[0]);
    }
    else
        return 0.0;
}
```

It is slower than `Boost.Geometry` but very stable. I run it for 2*10^5 time steps overnight and it didn't crash. It took 6h 12min, while Boost would take about 4h, but I am happy.

**EDIT:**

I had rewritten some of the other functions, so the comparison was unfair to Clipper! For the same configuration and 100K time steps, Clipper completed the operation in 2h 36min which I find very nice! Boost would complete the same operation in approximately 2h 15min, so I find them very comparable for these long runs!

Comment: The authors of the paper you mentioned published an implementation of their algorithm and for verification purposes the polymerization-method (the code you just used). The analytical approach is ~10 times faster than the numerical one. Is there any reasons why you prefer the polygon-approach over the analytical solution?